# R Custom Order Output Of paste0

Tags: r, paste

I desire to paste text in specific order. This is my attempt at it:

```
paste0("car",1:3, "conv",1:3)
```

but this gives `"car1conv1" "car2conv2" "car3conv3"`

my desired outputs are:

`"car1","conv1","car2","conv2","car3","conv3"`

i am not sure how to do the ordering other than doing it manually but just imagine having to do this for 100 items, so i am seeking assitance in generating this type of output in 1 or 2 steps thanks so much.

Comment: Try `paste0(c("car", "conv"), rep(1:3, each = 2))`

Comment: @ronak shah how would you get this output: "car1","car2","car3", "conv1", conv2","conv3"

Comment: you can just change the `each` in `paste0(c("car", "conv"), rep(1:3,  2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `repl`icate one them and use `paste0`

```
paste0(c("car", "conv"), rep(1:3, each = 2))
#[1] "car1"  "conv1" "car2"  "conv2" "car3"  "conv3"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(c("car", "conv"), 1:3, paste0))
#[1] "car1"  "conv1" "car2"  "conv2" "car3"  "conv3"
```

Comment: how would you get this output: "car1","car2","car3", "conv1", conv2","conv3"

Comment: @bvowe you can transpose the output `c(t(outer(c("car", "conv"), 1:3, paste0)))`